# Unable to downloading the Maven artifacts

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I am using global level maven with version 3.2.1. I have just installed the maven and set up the environment variable like below.

`M2={User.Home}/.m2;`

`M2_Home="C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.2.1";`

`MAVEN_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin";`

`MVN_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin"`

Then i run the command mvn clean:build in command prompt. But warning messages are coming like unable to download the artifacts.

Here i am not using any proxy server. I am connected to company network.

Thanks,
Narsi p

Comment: Please post the error you are getting

Comment: Please try running maven with -X option, this will give you additional debug info, which might provide more information.

Comment: C:\Users\pnar>mvn clean:build
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or on
e of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

Comment: Try to move the maven installation directory to some other directory where there is no space. For example c:\apps\maven. I remember somewhere reading spaces should not be there

Comment: In my machine i have only one directory that is c: drive only.

Answer (score 0):

Download the zip file for apache-maven ,extract and keep in c:\apache-maven-3.2.1 .Rename your folder name to maven insted of apache-maven-3.2.1 and set the environment variable to

```
MAVEN_HOME="C:\maven";
```

And in path you include this like below after jdk path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;
```

Now try to run. Hope it works.

Comment: What's not working . what error your getting ? Did you followed the steps mentioned above.

Comment: ya i followed the same steps what you mentioned.I am getting following error :C:\Users\pnar>mvn clean:build [INFO] Scanning for projects... Downloading: repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven- clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave n-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or on e of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5